# Change Woocommerce Admin Order List Time and Date Format

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi Im trying to change the time and date format via functions.php but it still displays last 24 hours order like "1 minute ago" or "2 hours ago". How do i get all orders to just display the order time and date on he admin order list? Any help is much appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sunrj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can read, there is a filter that hooks the date format: `woocommerce_admin_order_date_format` - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/a7d57a248ed03dac7bad119e71f83dd961f43cb3/includes/admin/list-tables/class-wc-admin-list-table-orders.php but it fires **only if** the order is older than 1 day.

Maybe that's why is not working.

Another elegant approach, without touching any template file would be to remove the native WooCommerce date columns and add a custom one.

Here is a code snippet **(untested)** you can paste in your functions.php file.

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'so61375632_add_new_order_admin_column' );
function so61375632_add_new_order_admin_column( $columns ) {

    unset( $columns['order_date'] ); // remove the default column

    $edit_columns = array_splice( $columns, 0, 2 );

    $edit_columns['order_custom_date'] = 'Date';

    return array_merge( $edit_columns, $columns );

}

add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column', 'so61375632_add_new_order_admin_column_content', 20, 2 );
function so61375632_add_new_order_admin_column_content( $column, $order_id ) {

    if ( $column == 'order_custom_date' ) {

        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

        if( ! is_wp_error( $order ) ) {

            echo $order->get_date_created()->format ('M j, Y H:i'); // pass any PHP date format 

        }

    }

}
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: That somewhat worked! However the date column is now 2 columns away from original position.  how do I move the date column so that It sits exactly where it was before (beside order status column) and also how do i show the time as well? Thank you so much!

Comment: Then please flag the answer as correct ;) I’ll update the code to show the time tomorrow.

Comment: 1)  It is not necessary to delete the original column and then create a new one. You can simply overwrite the original column. 2) The use of `global $post` is not necessary either, the `$post_id` is passed as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: @AshrafAli time added and column repositioned ;) 7uc1f3r good hint about #2, thanks! Not sure about #1 as it would add content, not replace the existing one.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion 7uc1f3r,  @FrancescoCarlucci it's working!

Comment: @FrancescoCarlucci im running into a new problem with the codes. Right now on the admin order list it displays the time wrongly. But when i click into the order it shows the correct time the order is made. So i tried removing the codes snippets from functions.php and revert back to "hours ago" date / time and it is correct "hours ago". What could be wrong here? P/s: i did a back up and migrated to a new host, and this started. Prior to that it was fine.